# Is there a pullup on I2C?

Tags: arduino-uno, i2c

I am using an Arduino Uno R3.

It is not clear on the schematic whether there are pullups on the A4 and A5 I2C pins.

Are there hardwired pullups or do I have to add them myself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are very weak internal pullups, but they are [not strong enough](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/102611/what-happens-if-i-omit-the-pullup-resistors-on-i2c-lines) to be considered compliant with I<sup>2</sup>C specs. Supply your own external 2.2k-10kohm pullup resistors.

Answer (score 0):

No. There are potential internal pullups, but not AFIK activated.

You can quite safely connect I²C to Raspberry P1 (3.3V).